# Import External CDN in React Component

Tags: html, reactjs, cdn, vis.js

I created the react application using create-react-app npm. I wanted to add external CDN of vis.js in my react app.js component but I am not able to find a way to add it. I tried adding cdn in my html page and also used one extra html page for scripts and import in app.js component but it didn't work out.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("In constructer");
  }

componentDidMount() {
  console.log("in componentDidMount");


  var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
    {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
    {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
    {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
    {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
  ]);

  // create an array with edges
  var edges = new vis.DataSet([
    {from: 1, to: 3},
    {from: 1, to: 2},
    {from: 2, to: 4},
    {from: 2, to: 5}
  ]);

  var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
  };

  var options = {

    edges:{
      arrows: {
          to:     {enabled: true, scaleFactor:1, type:'arrow'},
          middle: {enabled: false, scaleFactor:1, type:'arrow'},
          from:   {enabled: false, scaleFactor:1, type:'arrow'}
      },
    },
    nodes:{
      shape:'square'
    },
    interaction:{
      dragNodes:false
    }
  };
  var network = new vis.Network(this.refs.myRef, data, options);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  console.log("in componentWillUnmount");
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <p className="App-intro">
        To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
      </p>
      <div ref="myRef"></div>;
    </div>
  );
}
}

class Header extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Now I wanted to add  this script in my app.js so that I can use new vis.* methods.

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.20.0/vis.min.js"></script>`

How can I add this cdn in my component?

Comment: Can you share the html page where you included the Cdn. I'm use cdn in my root html page successfully without any issues.

Comment: hi, actually I wanted to use vis.js in my react App.js file so I need to include CDN in that file only. I already added CDN in my html file but it didn't work.

Comment: Depending on what vis.js does. Why don't you download it via npm and then import it into a store or class. If you can reproduce this on fiddle, i will be happy to take a look and help you resolve it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add the CDN normally in Your index.html file and then in Your React component use window.* where the star is the name of the function to access this function. For example if this CDN has a function countSomething() You invoke it by using window.countSomething().

Comment: You saved my day! However, does cdn hosted package have any disadvantage over locally installed npm package?

Comment: @SeaWarrior404 By using npm package You're going to be able to bundle all the code together, including the libraries and host it Yourself. This minimizes the amount of requests that the browser has to do. The CDN though has much better reach around the world with low latency and they have perfect caching configuration for when You don't update it much and have clients worldwide. You have to decide for Yourself how much You want to bundle and how many different CDNs You want to use. Using too many different CDNs slows things down too compared to single CDN serving many files.

Comment: I don't understand , I think there is no .html file in React

Comment: @Neko There's always an .html file, since react app has to be injected in a website to run as javascript script.

Answer (score 0):

You can import any CDN script by using `createElement()` of ReactJs.

Here's an example of importing FontAwesome (although we can directly use `React-Icons` instead) using CDN script.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  };
```